# Is Bitcoin still vulnerable to CVE-2012-2459 attack today?

Tags: bitcoin

The Bitcoin [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/merkle.cpp) still carries a warning that states "...algorithm has a serious flaw..."

But, [this site](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures)  seems to suggest it has been fixed. I am confused.

Could you please clarify if it has been fixed or not? If it has, why would that scaring warning still be necessary?

Comment: According to https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2012-05-14-dos#risks   `Because this bug could be exploited to severely disrupt the Bitcoin network we consider this a critical vulnerability, and encourage everybody to upgrade to the latest version: 0.6.2.  Backports for older releases (0.5.5 and 0.4.6) are also available if you cannot upgrade to version 0.6.2.`  Which implies 0.6.2 doesn't have it.

Comment: Did you see the end of the comment `We defend against this by...`  The warning is to tell people not to use the code *outside* of Bitcoin, since the mitigation might not help in other use cases.

Comment: @NateEldredge I accept your comment as an answer. Thanks.